# Grid is not refreshed by Ajax call

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am facing this problem in my project, for simply to re-generate same issue, I created test project but issue is still.

I have a grid view. I am binding it initially with some values and after clicking button, I am binding it with different data source. But it shows same data.

C#:

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        static Default def;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            grdTest.DataSource = new List<Employee> { 
                                     new Employee {Age = "26", Gender = "Male", Name = "A"},
                                     new Employee {Age = "26", Gender = "Male", Name = "B"},
                                     new Employee {Age = "26", Gender = "Male", Name = "C"}
                                    };
            grdTest.DataBind();
            def = this;

        }

        public void Bind()
        {
             GridView gr = (GridView)def.FindControl("grdTest");
             gr.DataSource = null;

             gr.DataSource = new List<Employee> { 
                                     new Employee {Age = "26", Gender = "Male", Name = "A"},
                                     new Employee {Age = "26", Gender = "Male", Name = "B"},
                                     new Employee {Age = "26", Gender = "Male", Name = "C"},
                                     new Employee {Age = "26", Gender = "Male", Name = "D"}
                                    };
             gr.DataBind();
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public static void TestMethod()
        {
            def.Bind();
        }
    }
    public class Employee
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }
    }
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("[id*=btnTest]").click(
                function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Default.aspx/TestMethod",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        // Passes id of current instance of user control
                        //data: "{ 'currentId': '" + $(input).attr("id").split("_").reverse()[1] + "' }",
                        success: function (response) {
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                        }
                    });
                });
        });
```

Comment: it doesn't work this way, you can't update page controls from web methods, its just there for ajax calls that return data (regardless of format), what you need, is a post to the page which will render only the grid and then replace it's html in the page